# Single array to store multiple variables in each element

Tags: java, arrays, graphics

EDIT: to clarify, one of my requirements is to use a single array.

I am having trouble storing multiple variables to a single element in an array.  We are creating a really simple program to mimic Microsoft Paint.  One of the requirements is to store each element I draw in to an array so that the 'paint' method repaints the drawings each time the windows is minimized and then redisplayed.  Here are the requirements

We are to assume a max size for the array is 20.
Each element should include 5 variables:

- char shape (l for line, r for rectangle, c for circle)
- Start x value
- Start y value
- width (rectangle), or ending x (line), or radius (circle)
- height (rectangle), or ending y (line), or radius (circle)

Here is my code for the array class:

```
class storeDraws {
    final int MAXSIZE = 20;
    static int S[];
    static int n; //number of draws user makes
    static char shape;
    static double px, py, w, h;

    storeDraws () {
        S = new int [MAXSIZE];
        n = 0;
        shape = 'l';
        px = 0;
        py = 0;
        w = 0;
        h = 0;
    }
}
```

I have read a few places that I can input the array as (using the mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) method:

```
storeDraws[] input = new storeDraws{value, value, value, value, value};
```

But I don't think that would work for what I am trying to do with the 'paint' method to redraw the shapes.  I thought I could somehow pass it using the standard format of S[n] = (char, double, double, double, double), but I get warning that this is illegal.

Edit 8:30 am
I got this part working.  In my class here is my code now.

```
class storeDraws {
    static char shape;
    static int px, py, w, h;

    storeDraws () {
        shape = 'l';
        px = 0;
        py = 0;
        w = 0;
        h = 0;
    }
}
```

I then declared this in the DrawPanel class:

```
private storeDraws[] store = new storeDraws[20];
private int n = 0;
```

And mouseReleased method of DrawPanel:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    if (drawShape == "line") {
        store[n].shape = 'l';
        store[n].px = p1.x;
        store[n].py = p1.y;
        store[n].w = p3.x;
        store[n].h = p3.y;
        n++;
    }
```

And paint:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (store[i].shape == 'l')
            g.drawLine(store[n].px, store[n].py, store[n].w, store[n].h);
```

But if I draw 6 lines it only repaints the last line.

Comment: An array only stores similar elements, so with `(char, double, double, ...)` you get an error.

Are you sure that you need an array? You might use a list or map.

Comment: You need to rethink how you're representing shapes. Make a `Shape` class, then create an array of that class, `Shape[]`. As it is now, your `storeDraws` class is trying to do both.

Comment: @hamena314 requirement of my assignment is to use an array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to separate some of the functionality you want. You can have a class for each of the elements and then store instances of the class in an array of DrawingElement objects.

So you'd do something like this:

```
DrawingElement[] drawing = new DrawingElement[20];
DrawingElement circle = new DrawingElement('c', 10, 10, 10, 10);
DrawingElement rect = new DrawingElement('r', 20, 10, 10, 10);
drawing[0] = circle;
drawing[1] = rect;
```

Note: If you need to be able to get the number of objects in the array (variable `n` in your code) you may want to use some implementation of 
a Linked List (which has a `size()` method) and do some check when adding elements to make sure you don't add past the max of 20.

Example with LinkedList:

```
LinkedList<DrawingElement> drawing = new LinkedList<DrawingElement>();
DrawingElement circle = new DrawingElement('c', 10, 10, 10, 10);
DrawingElement rect = new DrawingElement('r', 20, 10, 10, 10);
drawing.add(circle);
drawing.add(rect);
int n = drawing.size(); //will be 2
```

The Drawing Element Class:

```
public class DrawingElement
{
    char shape;
    double px, py, w, h;

    public DrawingElement(char shape, double px, double py, double w, double h)
    {
         this.shape = shape;
         this.px = px;
         this.py = py;
         this.w = w;
         this.h = h;
    }

    //Add getters and setters (accessors and mutators) for class variables
}
```

Comment: @ChrisCampbell, @Avantol13 Note: `shape`, `px`, etc should not be `static`, as that means there's one value for **all** `DrawingElement` instances.

Comment: @kuporific edited. Copy and pasted and didn't look it over well enough :/ thanks

Comment: @kuporific Thanks guys, this helped a lot.  Now I just have to figure out how to redraw these using the "public void paint(Graphics g)" method.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @ChrisCampbell I don't see anything obviously wrong in the paint method in your question. If you're having issues, though, I would recommend asking another question so that each question is focused and since this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use collection for this purpose.Create array, store values
then add each array object in collection(list).

Answer (score 0):

First point, We cannot store different types of variables values into an Array.

An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type.
Here you are trying to store multiple type of variables into integer array.

see this link:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

To overcome this drawback, We have Collection API introduced with JDK1.5

Refer this link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use arraylist instead of array. this will help you to store different variable.
If there is need of using only array you can use object array
Sample Code
object a[]= {'a',10,10.2,10.3,10.4,10.5}

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

In your case it would be better to use Java Collection(ArrayList) rather than Array.

Comment: One of the requirements is to use a single array, not an arraylist.

Comment: @ChrisCampbell i have posted one more answer with the code cnippet , please refer that if your want to stick to the requirement.